# Failing C Function to Accept User String Array Input

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc

I am trying to create a C function I can call in small programs I write, to accept user input:

```
char GetStringMine()
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    char * tmpstring = (char *) malloc(2048 * sizeof(char));
    while(ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        tmpstring[i++] = ch;
    }
    tmpstring[i] = '\0';
    return * tmpstring;
    free(tmpstring);
}
```

But it does not compile.
Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong, and what I can do better?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: What do you think these two lines `return * tmpstring;
    free(tmpstring);` will do?

Comment: Apparently they make me seem dumber. :-)

Comment: Every thing happens after `return` statement wont meter anymore.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.

Answer (score 2):

- First thing:

  In your code,

  ```
   while(ch != '\n')
  ```

  invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as `ch` is an automatic local variable and unless initialized explicitly, it contains an indeterminate value. Trying to read an indeterminate value is UB.
- Second thing,

  ```
  free(tmpstring);
  ```

  after the `return` statement has no effect, at all. Just remove it.
- Third thing:

  [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- Fourth thing:

  As per your `return` statement, the function return type should be of `char *`, instead of a `char`.

Finally

> *But it does not compile*

cannot be answered in current form. You need to provide more information in your question to clarify "what" and "how".

Comment: True, but none of these are gonna stop compilation of program.

Comment: Sorry. The actual content of comment was changed. May be I pressed some other keys while posting.

Comment: @haccks Right sir, that's why I added the last statement in the _answer_. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
static char tmpstring[2048] = {0};

char* GetStringMine()
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch = 0;

    while(ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        tmpstring[i++] = ch;
    }

    return tmpstring;  
}
```

- You cannot free the allocated memory then return a pointer to it, the data will be gone
- No need to use malloc, as you are not dynamically allocating the array(1)
- Return a char*, not a char

(1) In your example you effectively are fixing the size of memory to 2048. Think about protecting against a buffer overrun - what will happen if a user enters more than 2048 characters, and how will you protect your code against this.
In a real world application you would need to reallocate if going over the allotted size, or restrict the amount of input for the memory allocated.

Comment: Your program is returning a pointer to a local variable (`tmpstring`) which will also be gone once the function has been called. Correct your answer or you'll certainly get downvotes.

Comment: Thanks, how can I dynamically allocate the array? I would like not to set it to fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a char pointer(char*) but the return type is a char. Also you should consider other comments too.

```
char* GetStringMine()
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    char * tmpstring = (char *) malloc(2048 * sizeof(char));
    while(ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        tmpstring[i++] = ch;
    }
    tmpstring[i] = '\0';
    return  tmpstring;
}
```

Comment: No. He is not trying to return `char *`.

Comment: he is, but he does not know that.

Comment: He isn't, he's dereferencing the char pointer which evaluates to a char.

Answer (score 0):

The worst thing about this code is that you're trying return a *pointer to a local variable*. The variable `tmpstring` is destroyed after the execution of your function is complete (*i.e.* on your `return` statement).

To correct this, you should ask a `char*` as a parameter, and store the read characters in it (careful with the overflows if you're going with this solution).

Or, you could declare `tmpstring` as a `static char tmpstring[2048] = {0};`. `static` means it won't be destroyed after the function is over. Although I've seen that kind of things in the standard library sometimes, I wouldn't recommend it since the contents will be erased when the function is called again.

For the other problems, see the previous answers.